# match keywords data to title mysql

Tags: mysqli

There are two tables Items, Tags

### Items Table

```
Item_Id  Item_title
1        ford car manufactured in year 1978 dallas
2        nissan, ford car parts dallas
3        travel paris cheap tickets
```

### Tags Table

```
tag_id  tag_name
1       ford
2       nissan
3       paris
4       dallas
```

now i need a query that can find the matched tags for item_title

### desired output

```
items_tags
----------
item_id  tag_id tag_name
1           1    ford
1           4    dallas
2           1    ford
2           2    nissan
2           4    dallas
```

looking for performance based query, thanks

Comment: Anyone can give me a solution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below query:

select I.Item_Id, I.Item_title, T.tag_id, T.tag_name from tblTags T Join tblItems I ON I.Item_title like '%' + T.tag_name + '%'

Comment: Please check this :   select I.Item_Id, I.Item_title, T.tag_id, T.tag_name from tblTags T Cross Join tblItems I 
 Where CHARINDEX(T.tag_name,I.Item_title, 0) > 0

Answer (score 0):

I have created "Full-Text Index" on Item_title column then my query execution time reduced from 38s to 10-15s.

Please try creating "Full-Text Index" on Item_title column

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/creating-full-text-index-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Usually searching the text in table will consume time. To avoid that create one mapping table with Item_id and Tag_Id.

**Create table tblItems_Tags_Mapping(
RefId  int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ItemId int references tblItems(Item_Id),
TagId int references tblTags(tag_id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tblItems_Tags_Index ON tblItems_Tags (ItemId, TagId);**

Then write one trigger on insert of Items, it will insert Tag_id, Item_Id in mapping table.

**CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Items_INSERT]
       ON [dbo].tblItems
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
    DECLARE @ItemId int;
   DECLARE @Title varchar(300);
   DECLARE @tag_id int;


   SELECT @ItemId =INSERTED.Item_Id,   @Title = INSERTED.Item_title       
   FROM INSERTED;

    Select @tag_id = tag_id from tblTags Where CHARINDEX(tag_name, @Title, 0) > 0  ; 
   INSERT INTO tblItems_Tags VALUES(@ItemId, @tag_id)
```

END**

**from this mapping table we can fetch the data.**

select I.*, T.tag_name from tblItems_Tags_Mapping I join  tblTags T On I.TagId = T.Tag_id